# Compiling Java Classes and Building jar Package Explicitly in Windows

Tags: java, class, jar, compilation, building

I Want to do all using CMD,

I was developing using Netbeans, but I want to compile all java files and to build jar package through **CMD** Windows.

Suppose I have this:

My position:

```
C:\>cd "Directory Default1"
C:\Directory Default1>
```

My JDK is located in:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\
```

**1. Compiling Java Classes**

My Output class files directory is:

```
D:\Developing Java\classes\hipack\lopack
```

My Source files directory  is:

```
D:\Developing Java\src\
```

For Compile I want to do something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\javac.exe" -d "D:\Developing Java\classes\hipack\lopack" "D:\Developing Java\src\hipack\lopack\*.java"
```

where **hipack** and **lopack** are the identifier of my package **hipack.lopack** project

From my position:

```
C:\Directory Default1>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\javac.exe" -d "D:\Developing Java\classes\hipack\lopack" "D:\Developing Java\src\hipack\lopack\*.java"
```

**2. Building jar Package**

My *manifest* file is located in:

```
D:\Developing Java\MANIFEST.MF
```

My Output jar files directory is:

```
D:\Developing Java\dist\

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\jar.exe" cvfm "D:\Developing Java\dist\hipack-lopack.jar" "d:\Developer\java\MANIFEST.MF" "D:\Developing Java\classes\" hipack/lopack
```

where my output jar file is:

```
hipack-lopack.jar
```

I want to know how to set the root directory from my package will be created:

```
"D:\Developing Java\classes\"
```

You can see I want to do all, using location in diferent folders never using **cd** to change to directory of classes... I want to do it "remotely"!!!

Comment: I can infer you want to generate the output in the path `D:\Developing Java\classes\"` but I'm not sure if you already have any of your ideas implemented. Anyway, assuming your commands are working the only error I see is when using javac the part `-d "D:\Developing Java\classes\hipack\lopack"` Will duplicate package folders if you have a `hipack.lopack` package. It will suffice by using `-d "D:\Developing Java\classes"` to prevent the folders duplication

Comment: I have problem with quotes, but the folder name includes spaces.... and I'm not sure if output classes files must be '-d "D:\Developing Java\classes\hipack\lopack"' or '-d "D:\Developing Java\classes"'...

Comment: It's `-d "D:\Developing Java\classes\"`

Comment: Unfortunately using quotes doesn't work...  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\javac.exe" -d "D:\Developing Java\classes\" "D:\Developing Java\src\hipack\lopack\\*.java"...